# How do you map the same entity to identical tables using Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework, entity

In my conceptual model I have a 'Box' that can contain 'x' number of widgets. Some of the widgets can be archived and are accessed infrequently. A box can contain one or more widgets. To support maximum database performance I want to use two identical database tables; one for normal widgets and one for archived widgets. I don't want the Box entity to have two different collections of widgets, eg `IList<ArchiveWidget> & IList<Widget>`, just one that contains both archived and active widgets.

How can I map the 'Box' entity to the 'Widget' entity that uses the archive and active tables at the same time?

Comment: You probably want to look into Table Per Type Inheritance. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738685.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is on way you could try to solve this: Create a view that is a union of NewWidget and ArchivedWidget. This would work for reading data.

Another alternative is to go into the edmx file and try an fix it there. But I do not think that this is possible, since if you create a new widget and say save, EF would not know which table to put it in.

You could generate the EF model with the two types, then move the type definition into a base class, which both of the widget inherit from. I have not tried this, therefore not sure if it will work.